# pgadmin plugins?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Where can I find plugins for pgadmin3?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any central repository of plugins, but the pgadmin debugger plugin can be found at

- For PgAdmin 3 - https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/debugger.html
- For PgAdmin 4 - https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/1.x/debugger.html